# Bootstrap4 hide show columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to be able to hide/show columns based upon the screen size.

Example:

- When the screen is eXtra Small <576px, I want 2 columns to show
- When the screen is MeDium ≥768px, I want 4 columns to show
- When the screen is eXtra Large ≥1200, I want 6 columns to show.

There are several hundred rows, so I don't want 3 tables, just the columns to show or hide based upon size.

JS Fiddle at: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tkcynbjk/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="d-none d-table-cell" scope="col">ALWAYS 1</th>
                <th class="d-none d-table-cell" scope="col">ALWAYS 2</th>
                <th class="d-none d-table-cell d-md-table-cell" scope="col">MED 1</th>
                <th class="d-none d-table-cell d-xl-table-cell" scope="col">XL ONLY 1</th>
                <th class="d-none d-table-cell d-md-table-cell" scope="col">MED 2</th>
                <th class="d-none d-table-cell d-xl-table-cell" scope="col">XL ONLY 2</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                    <td>E</td>
                    <td>F</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work when you remove the `d-table-cell` classes.

Run the snippet full-screen to see the media queries work, or check out your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/tkcynbjk/1/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="" scope="col">ALWAYS 1</th>
                    <th class="" scope="col">ALWAYS 2</th>
                    <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">MED 1</th>
                    <th class="d-none d-xl-table-cell" scope="col">XL ONLY 1</th>
                    <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">MED 2</th>
                    <th class="d-none d-xl-table-cell" scope="col">XL ONLY 2</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td  class="d-none d-md-table-cell">C</td>
                        <td class="d-none d-xl-table-cell">D</td>
                        <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">E</td>
                        <td class="d-none d-xl-table-cell">F</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!